# Is it possible to make Thunderbird not to show inline images as attachments?

Tags: thunderbird

I get very annoyed when I get a message in Thunderbird with 20 attachments, most of them being just small inline images and such, with only a file or two.

Is it possible to make Thunderbird not to display such images as attachments?

I tried playing with the **mail.inline_attachments** but that didn't change the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest "Display attachments inline" checkbox lets you send your attachments directly to other users when sending email. If you'd like to do this remove the checkmark from this menu item.

Comment: That is the exact setting I tried (mail.inline_attachments).